# Equivalent method for JSON unknown variables

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using webapi which accepts both JSON/XML.I have customized the XML formatter for removing the namespace and to find the unknown elements along with the request by adding handler to the serializer.

```
//Override method ReadFromStreamAsync in custom xml formatter.
//Adding event handler for unknown elements.
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
serializer.UnknownElement += Serializer_UnknownElement;
private static void Serializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
    { to find the unknown elements}
```

There is any method like Serializer_UnknownElement is available for JSON to find the unknown elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Json.Net you can catch all unknown values in the Json in a dictionary in your model by using the [JsonExtensionDataAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm).

So in your model you want to add something like

```
[JsonExtensionData]
public IDictionary<string, JToken> UnknownValues { get; set; }
```

From there you could just have some code which checks if there is anything in that dictionary and then calls some custom method if that's what you need.